# Identify method's signature using inherited classes in Java's abstract methods

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract

I know this is a very simple question, but I have been working in Python for quite a long time and now that I must go back to Java, I seem to have problems *changing the chip* and wrapping my head around Java's basic polymorphism.

Is it possible to overwrite (implement, to be precise) a class' `abstract` method in Java using one of the inherited classes as argument?

Let me explain with a very simple example (following the *"almost official"* [example](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/hellofadude/archive/2014/01/07/polymorphism-java) with shapes)

```
class Shape {}
class Circle extends Shape {}
class Triangle extends Shape {}

abstract class ShapeDrawer {
    abstract void draw(Shape s); 
}                       
class CircleDrawer extends ShapeDrawer {
    void draw(Circle c){
        System.out.println("Drawing circle");
    }
}
```

Is there any way of having Java identifying the `draw` method in the `CircleDrawer` class as the implementation of the abstract `draw` in `ShapeDrawer`? (The `Circle` class extends from `Shape` after all)

Otherwise put: What I'd like is that the `draw` method of the `CircleDrawer` class accepts only instances of type `Circle`, but at the same time, I'd like to tell the Java compiler that the `void draw(Circle c)` is actually the implementation of the abstract method `abstract void draw(Shape s)` located in its parent class.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I may just be reading this wrong, but if that isn't what you want can you provide an example as to what you DO want?

Comment: @Aify, I've edited the question describing what I'd want to achieve. Hopefully is clearer now? Let me know if it isn't.

Comment: Don't forget to power off before you yank that chip out.

Comment: `public abstract void ShapeDrawer` your'e putting a return method for a class declaration?

Comment: You have two different declarations of the ShapeDrawer class -- one is abstract and one is not.  Which one do you want?

Comment: Please check for compilation errors before you post code, it's full of them and a lot of things are unclear.

Comment: @MikeClark, No: I wanted to show what I didn't want (as a clarification) but it clearly was more confusing than helpful. (I edited the question to remove it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve your problem by means of generics:

```
public abstract class ShapeDrawer<T extends Shape> {
    public abstract void draw(T shape);
}

public class CircleDrawer extends ShapeDrawer<Circle> {
    public void draw(Circle circle) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't and there is a very good reason why you can't. Take this declaration

```
public abstract class ShapeDrawer {
    public abstract void draw(Shape s); 
}
```

Now take some code that receives a `ShapeDrawer` and tries to use it:

```
public void foo(ShapeDrawer drawer, Shape shape) {
    drawer.draw(shape);
}
```

This code should work because the declaration of `ShapeDrawer` promises that whoever implements it will provide a method called `draw()` and that method can deal with any `Shape`.

But if you were allowed to do this:

```
public class CircleDrawer extends ShapeDrawer {
    public void draw(Circle c) {...}
}
```

That would no longer hold true, your `CircleDrawer` would be unable to satisfy the promise that it can deal with any `Shape`.

---

However imagine this declaration:

```
public abstract class ShapeCreator {
    public abstract Shape create();
}

public class CircleCreator extends ShapeCreator {
    public Circle create() {...}
}
```

Would this work?

Yes, it would(provided that you use Java 5 or later), because unlike the first declaration, what `ShapeCreator` promises is that it will have a method called `create()`, which will return a `Shape`. Since `Circle` is a `Shape`, a subclass of `ShapeCreator` can decide to return only `Circle`s, no promises are broken.

---

So how do you achieve what you want? See [loonytune's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30470208/574479) :)

Answer (score 1):

Not technically, but you can do a hack around it for the functionality you specified.

```
public abstract ShapeDrawer {
    public abstract void draw(Shape s); 
}                       
public CircleDrawer extends ShapeDrawer {
    public void draw(Shape s){
        if (s instanceof Circle) {
            System.out.println("Drawing circle");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is OK, but essentially the same as the generics example already given.  I'd prefer generics if I'm going to do something like this.

Comment: It's close, but not close enough to say it's the same. By doing it this way, you can still technically pass in other shapes, and do other kinds of handling - eg: print "this is not a circle", or something like that. But buy using Generics, you're not even allowed to call it with something that isn't a Circle.

Comment: Internally, all the generics does is test the instance type similar to what you did.  However, the compiler should *prevent* you from passing anything that isn't a Circle, and in most cases that's a big win.

Comment: Most cases - Like I said, this technically allows for other handling instead of just straight up blocking it. I have no idea why anyone would want that, but I think the point is more that it's an option, not that this is better than the generics method. @markspace

Answer (score 0):

No, Java method signatures must match exactly, you can't use subtypes, or you'll overload a method instead of overriding it.

You can *return* a subtype, but that's it, and return types aren't part of a method signature.